# What would be the referred interface when we have multiple inheritance with same method name. in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

In the following code ,the method `a.x()` refers to Interface `I1` or `I2`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();

        a.x();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class A:I1,I2
{

    public void x()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
interface I1
{
    void x();
}

interface I2
{
    void x();
}
```

Comment: Both.  Just try it.  If you don't want that then you'll have to write an explicit interface method implementation to resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

`a.x()` refers both interfaces `I1` and `I2`.

Answer (score 0):

Since they have the same signature, `a.x()` satisfies both interfaces.

If you want different implementations you can specify the interface to which  the implementation applies by prefixing it with the interface name:

```
class A : I1, I2
{

    public void I1.x()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello I1");
    }

    public void I2.x()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello I2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not really multiple inheritance, because you don't inherit behaviour. If you inherit from multiple classes, it would be different (which isn't possible in C#). You just implement interfaces here, and both interfaces are satisfied.